# Codechef : Correct approach or not?

Tags: c, algorithm

http://www.codechef.com/OCT14/problems/PRLADDU

This is a current running competition.
I don't want it's answer, just let me know whether my approach is right or not.

The approach I have followed is to add people and dinos commutatively and add up the steps (commutatively again) taken by them to calculate the final answer.

If my approach is correct then which case is failing (what am I overlooking) as the compiler says wrong answer? Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int t=0,n=0,i=0,dnv=0,grass=0,j=0;
    int d[100000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        scanf("%d",&d[j]);

        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
            dnv+=d[j];
            if(dnv>0)
                grass=grass+dnv;
            else
                grass=grass-dnv;
        }
        printf("%d\n",grass);
        grass=dnv=0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What are the Prerequisites to attempt this problem http://www.codechef.com/OCT14/problems/FATCHEF
Thank you.

Comment: Good on you for saying that this problem is from a currently active contest.  Most people prefer to wait till it's over before giving help on such problems, so if you "bump" the question then, you should get more responses.

Comment: I guess, though I think those downvotes are a bit unfair in this case, seeing as you were up-front about the competition!  Best of luck in any case :)

Comment: There's a fair amount of frustration with Stack Overflow management's pigheaded insistence that questions about running contest problems are on topic despite the fact that they have net negative utility. CodeChef has plenty of practice problems, and by not waiting with questions like this one, you're wasting a lot of people's time.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I understand what you are saying but a simple knowledge of knowing whether I am on the right track or not helps to validate the direction of my effort.

Comment: @Amit0191: CodeChef does have their own rules and Code of Conduct that are prominently posted on the contest page. You should try to respect that if you are going to participate in their contests.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat ok fair enough.

Comment: If I don't understand a problem or a part of it, can I ask something to clarify that or that's frowned upon as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend your approach is absolutely right , Only check your **datatype** to print answer .
Your answer may come >10000000000 for any test case . check it, Its open forum , So I won't mention by pointing.

Comment: Please use uppercase letter when needed, and only when needed. Also, AFAIK, you should write `won't` instead of `willn't`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions , i'll take care next time

Comment: @Ambika Because of you I pay extra attention to these end cases,so thank you.